# Programatically starting a process in a control group in Go or C

Tags: go, cgroups

I basically want the functionality of `cgexec`, but called from a C or Go program (kinda like fork), and I couldn't find any such functionality in an existing library.

I understand that I could just use `exec` in Go, but this seems kinda ugly, and I feel like there must be a more idiomatic way to achieve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Summary: Just run **cgexec** to start the process.  Note that **cgexec** **exec()**s the desired program.  It doesn't **fork()** and run it in the background.

TL;DR; 
I'm speaking from relative ignorance here - I've got the same problem and am in the process of working out how to do it.  However, I think that the solution is pretty clear.  Here's my analysis:

From looking at **cgexec**'s source in  *cgexec.c*, you can see that main() does three things:

- The usual parameter parsing.
- Does <stuff> to find or create the appropriate cgroup environment.  (No, I don't understand the particulars of this, but I don't think that it matters.)
- At the end, it just calls **execvp()**.  It does *not* **fork()**.

Remember that **cgexec** is a binary.  It is **not** a library.

My take on this is that the binary puts *itself* in the requested cgroup environment and then execs the requested program.

To do this purely in golang, you'd have to start a new process and then exec the binary inside that - which is exactly the same thing that **cgexec** does.  There's no easy/straightforward way to do that by writing golang code within your program.  You *do not* want to fork inside a golang program!

Since you're going to have to fork/exec *something*, you may as well just use **os.StartProcess** or **os/exec.Command(...).Run()** to run **cgexec**.  It's completely safe and you're guaranteed to get the same hopefully well-known semantics as **cgexec**.